# Regex challenge - find "foobar" in HTML document

Tags: regex, regex-negation, dom

I have a fairly long and complex HTML document, and I need to find all occurences of a given string, e.g. "foobar", unless it's between `<a>` and `</a>` anchor tags.

The trouble is: it could be inside some text between the anchor tags, e.g.

```
<a>this is a foobar test</a>
```

and even in this case, I should *not* find the match.

How can I do that with a regex?? I would have no trouble finding `<a>foobar</a>` and so on - but finding every "foobar" *except* when it's between the anchor tags and surrounded by possible a lot of other text seems a bit tricky.....

Any ideas??

**ANSWER:**
We ended up using this Regex to solve this problem - just in case anyone is a) curious, or b) in the same place :-)

```
(?<!\<A.*(?=\<\/A))Test(?!\<\/A.*(?=\<A))
```

Comment: As Bart commented, regex solutions for parsing HTML tend to either fail on some cases (embedded tags) or be extremely complex. Consider using a DOM parser instead to find all the text in anchor tags, then do a string search or regex on that.

Comment: Correction - use the DOM to search text nodes that are not contained within anchor tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'foobar(?![^<]*</a>)'
```

works for me in the simplest case. it's obviously not resistant to having other tags within `a` tag.

Comment: the problem with this is it doesn't take into account something like: <a> asdf <b>foobar</b> </a>

Comment: Yes, that works, only if the a-tags don't have other tags in them: '<a> this is a foobar <b> foobar </b> test</a>'.

Comment: If the OP's content with the majority of cases, then all is fine: your solution is a heck of a lot easier to read than the more complex solution (who cover even more than the vast majority of cases :)).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do with negative lookahead and loohbehind patterns.  Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: OK, got it to work quite nicely with the regex expression `(?<!<a.*)foobar` - in C# / .NET this seems to apply to each line and for my purposes, that's just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'foobar <a>this is a foobar <span>foobar</span> test</a> foobar';

$pattern = '<a(?:[^"\'>]+|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*>(?:[^<]+|(?!<\/a\s*>)<)*<\/a\s*>';
$parts = preg_split('/('.$pattern.')/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$isLink = (bool) preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'$/', $parts[0]);
foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    if (!$isLink) {
        $part = str_replace('foobar', '!!!found!!!', $part);
    }
    $isLink = !$isLink;
}
$str = implode('', $parts);

echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

Comment: @marc_s: That’s PHP. Sorry, I somehow assumed you asked for a PHP solution. ;-)

Comment: thanks! No, I'm dealing with C# / .NET / jQuery here - but thanks anyway - I'll translate and see if I can make sense of it :-)

Comment: Well, the algorithm is just to split the string at the A elements you want to avoid, iterate the parts and replace *foobar* only in those parts that are not A elements. Since the result of `preg_split` is always an array where two consecutive items are not the same type (A element – anything except an A element), the flag `$isLink` is used to tell the type that is switched on each iteration.